# converting an MySQL QUERY to Flask_SQLALCHEMY: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'group_by'

Tags: mysql, sql-server, datetime, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Please I just want to convert these queries into a flask_sqlalchemy queries:

```
#Select Month(delivery_time), certificate_type, report_sent, count(*) from casepage.certificates group by Month(delivery_time), certificate_type, report_sent;
#Select Date(delivery_time), certificate_type, report_sent, count(*) from casepage.certificates group by Date(delivery_time), certificate_type, report_sent;
#Select Week(delivery_time), certificate_type, report_sent, count(*) from casepage.certificates group by Week(delivery_time), certificate_type, report_sent;
#Select Year(delivery_time), Month(delivery_time), certificate_type, report_sent, count(*) from casesite.certificates group by Year(delivery_time), Month(delivery_time), certificate_type, report_sent;
```

I tried this query but returned an error called AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'group_by'

```
daily=db.session.query(func.count(func.DATE(Certificates.delivery_time)), func.count(Certificates.certificate_type), func.count(Certificates.report_sent)).group_by((Certificates.certificate_type)).all()
      
   
weekly=db.session.query(sa.func.week(Certificates.delivery_time), Certificates.certificate_type, Certificates.report_sent).count().group_by(Certificates.certificate_type)
monthly= db.session.query(sa.func.month(Certificates.delivery_time), Certificates.certificate_type, Certificates.report_sent).count().group_by(Certificates.certificate_type)
```

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. This site is a QA site. Also sql server <> mysql.

Comment: Thank you, can you help on areas I can research better. because am not so familiar with flask alchemy thought I could get some clarification. Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure it out and here is how the query should look like in flask_sqlalchemy:

```
            day_extract = db.session.query(sa.func.date(Certificates.delivery_time),Certificates.certificate_type,Certificates.report_sent,func.count(sa.func.date(Certificates.delivery_time)),func.count(Certificates.report_sent),func.count(Certificates.certificate_type ) ).group_by(sa.func.date(Certificates.delivery_time),Certificates.certificate_type, Certificates.report_sent ).all() 
            week_extract = db.session.query(sa.func.week(Certificates.delivery_time),Certificates.certificate_type,Certificates.report_sent,func.count(sa.func.week(Certificates.delivery_time)),func.count(Certificates.report_sent),func.count(Certificates.certificate_type ) ).group_by(sa.func.week(Certificates.delivery_time),Certificates.certificate_type, Certificates.report_sent ).all()
            month_extract = db.session.query(sa.func.month(Certificates.delivery_time),Certificates.certificate_type,Certificates.report_sent,func.count(sa.func.month(Certificates.delivery_time)),func.count(Certificates.report_sent),func.count(Certificates.certificate_type ) ).group_by(sa.func.month(Certificates.delivery_time),Certificates.certificate_type, Certificates.report_sent ).all()
            year_extract = db.session.query(sa.func.year(Certificates.delivery_time),Certificates.certificate_type,Certificates.report_sent,func.count(sa.func.year(Certificates.delivery_time)),func.count(Certificates.report_sent),func.count(Certificates.certificate_type ) ).group_by(sa.func.year(Certificates.delivery_time),Certificates.certificate_type, Certificates.report_sent ).all()
```

I am opened to a better way